# Open/LibreOffice Calc data "extend selection" stops at blank rows

Tags: openoffice-calc, libreoffice-calc

I have a spreadsheet and have right clicked on a column header then selected Sort from menu. The dialog box provides an option to extend the selection, which I accept. The problem is that the selection is extended only for first three rows, then seeing a blank row, it ignores the rest of the rows after that.

Any way to alter that behavior .. say .. to actually select all of the data?

I am using Libreoffice 3.5.7.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a very standard LibreOffice 3.5.3.2 under Ubuntu 12.04LTS <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> will extend the selection to the next blank row, so repeated depression of the down arrow (while holding down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> simultaneously) steps down to successive blank rows (or parts thereof) while leaving the top of the selection unchanged.

Tested on a small sample, from Row1, with odd numbers in odd-numbered rows in ColumnA. Also that and with even numbers in even-numbered rows in ColumnC. Also both scenarios tested starting in Row3.

Once selected sorting, ascending or descending, of or on ColumnA or ColumnC works as I expect.

Also tested with OpenOffice Calc (4.1.3 on Widows 8.1) with similar results. "Extend the selection" reduces the number of rows selected (to and not including first side-by-side blanks) but sorting those, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Down</kbd> extends the selection downwards (when only blank rows remain in ColumnA, all the way to the end).

Answer (score 0):

It seems likely there were no way to do this: the recommended approach is to create a filter to select the blank rows, then delete the blank rows.

I will leave this question open in case someone has a 'real' answer i.e that does not require deleting blank rows.

Comment: It is not possible to select more data after the blank row. The downvote was inappropriate.

Comment: I tried it many times, including after closing/reopening. Have you tried it in your own copy of a spreadsheet? If so then report your steps to make this work - if you do in fact find a resolution the  downvote could be justified.

Answer (score 0):

Move the column to the last column and then sort with expanding selection